# Python Terminate subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run a script in Python that executes certain programs at a certain time of the day.

The script works, but every time I close the program it always reopen.  What I want is when the program opens, after 5 seconds it closes again.

How can I do that?

```
import subprocess
import schedule
import time

def job():
    subprocess.call ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AnyDesk\\AnyDesk.exe')

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: So do you want a way for Python to open up a task with `subprocess` then close it after 5 seconds... and repeat this indefinitely?  A more relevant question is - why do you need to use Python?

Comment: Why not schedule over cronjob?

Comment: @Bernardo The user looks like they're using Windows, so `cron` wouldn't work.  Maybe they can use Powershell combined with `TASKKILL`: https://sumtips.com/how-to/automatically-start-and-close-programs-at-specific-time/

Comment: Do you mean, when you close AnyDesk, it reopens?  That definitely should not happen.  This should run the app once, then sit idle for another 24 hours.  There's nothing about 5 seconds here.

Comment: Time until the next execution --> in https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html